# Setting up headers with `srcbook` in List of Tables/Figures

Tags: header-footer

How to create proper headers for the list of table/figure as stated in the chapter/section part? Here is a dummy example that generate the problem:

```
\documentclass[
  listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,
  a5paper,
  fontsize=7pt,% changed!
  %openright,% default
  %twoside=true% default
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[headsepline=true,
  %autooneside = false% not needed with the default twoside=true
]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\AfterTOCHead{\pagestyle{plain}}
\AfterStartingTOC{\clearpage}

\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\Blindtext[20]

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=21pc]{example-image-a} 
    \caption{\Blindtext[20]}
\end{figure}


\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use page style `plain` in LoF, LoT etc. then remove the following lines from the preamble:

```latex
\AfterTOCHead{\pagestyle{plain}}
\AfterStartingTOC{\clearpage}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
  listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,
  a5paper,
  fontsize=7pt
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[headsepline=true,
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\AfterTOCHead{\pagestyle{plain}}% <- remove this!
%\AfterStartingTOC{\clearpage}% <- remove this!

\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\Blindtext[20]

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=21pc]{example-image-a} 
    \caption{Caption text}
\end{figure}

\addtocontents{lof}{\Blindtext[20]}% dummy text to get more pages in LoF

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfect! It was sufficent to only remove\AfterTOCHead{\pagestyle{plain}}